# MAMP Pro can't start MySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I had to force a shutdown when my computer froze, and MAMP has been unable to start MySql since then. I have tried deleting the log files from MAMP/DB/mysql and restarting MAMP, but it hasn't worked. I also tried entering `sudo killall -9 mysqld` in the terminal, to no avail.

Here is the error log from MAMP:

```
2017-05-12 16:05:49 4691 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 730255276 and 730255276 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 730624549 in the ib_logfiles!2017-05-12 16:05:49 4691 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-05-12 16:05:49 4691 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-05-12 16:05:49 4691 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-05-12 16:05:50 4691 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_worker_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wordpress@0020test@0020site/wp_term_taxonomy which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./wordpress@0020test@0020site/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
2017-05-12 16:05:50 7fff7303b000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./wordpress@0020test@0020site/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170512 16:05:50 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you _read_ the thing? It gives you three options, what more do you need from us?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not too familiar with MAMP. I tried the third option, but it yielded no results and the file actually changed itself back. Would you mind explaining the first two choices, what files they're talking about, and what changes to make to them?

Comment: Well, first there's this message giving you the file name: `Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./wordpress@0020test@0020site/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd`. It's been a long time since I last worked with MAMP, but if things stayed the same, that file would be located in `MAMP/db/mysql/...`. Then the first option talks about ownership and/or file permissions, as in `chown`/`chmod`. The second option is pretty unambiguous...

Comment: I tried removing the file as per #2, and its permissions seem normal. Still no dice. Any other pointers? Thanks for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem with *MAMP*.

To solve the problem, i was forced to delete the file that causes the error located in *"Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/bib"* and then recreate the TABLE/BASE afterwards.

I hope that would be helpful.